# XML to LINQ with metadata

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I'm very new to both XML and LINQ. I've read several XML to LINQ tutorials, but none of the XML documents seem to be formatted the way mine is. I'm not sure if (and how) it changes things.

All the examples I've read on the internet seem to follow this format:

```
<data>
<row>
  <Term>201320</Term>
  <Subj>ACCT</Subj>
  <Subj_desc>Accounting</Subj_desc>
</row>
<row>
  <Term>201320</Term>
  <Subj>ACCT</Subj>
  <Subj_desc>Accounting</Subj_desc>
</row>
</data>
```

If I wanted to read that I think the code would look something like this:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load("URLHERE.xml");

var term = from row in document.Descendants("row")
select new
{
Term = row.Element("Term").Value,
Subject = row.Element("Subj").Value,
Subject_Description = row.Element("Subj_desc").Value,
};
```

Here's the problem: my XML document doesn't follow the same format. Instead of repeating the different tags for each term, it has a set of metadata at the top and then uses the SAME tag for each set of data.

Here's a sample of my XML document:

```
<metadata>
  <item name="TERM" type="xs:string" length="128"/>
  <item name="SUBJ" type="xs:string" length="128"/>
  <item name="SUBJECT_DESC" type="xs:string" length="512"/>
</metadata>
<data>
<row>
  <value>201320</value>
  <value>ACCT</value>
  <value>Accounting</value>
</row>
<row>
  <value>201320</value>
  <value>ACCT</value>
  <value>Accounting</value>
</row>
</data>
```

How would I extract data from it?

```
var term = from row in document.Descendants("row")
select new
{
Term = row.Element("value").Value,
Subject = row.Element("value").Value,
};
```

Doesn't seem right. I'm using C# BTW (not sure if I need to say that or if the tag's sufficient).

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is not properly formatted, you need a root element that encapsulates the entire document. such as

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<root>
<metadata>
  <item name="TERM" type="xs:string" length="128"/>
  <item name="SUBJ" type="xs:string" length="128"/>
  <item name="SUBJECT_DESC" type="xs:string" length="512"/>
</metadata>
<data>
<row>
  <value>201320</value>
  <value>ACCT</value>
  <value>Accounting</value>
</row>
<row>
  <value>201320</value>
  <value>ACCT</value>
  <value>Accounting</value>
</row>
</data>
</root>
```

Then using XDocument you could load the file

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
```

then you can extract the data, kinda depends what you want to extract, you never specified. example of getting the metadata

```
var item = doc.Descendants("metadata");
```

getting rows, containing an IEnumerable of values

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load("c:\\tmp\\test.xml");
var rows = from i in document.Descendants("row")
           select new {values = i.Elements("value").Select(a=>a.Value)};
```

Comment: Regarding the incorrectly formatted XML document, the original is correct, left that off my sample by accident. 

I'm trying to extract anything between the <value> tags. Eventually I either want to run a query on the XML or throw all of it into a list (I haven't decided which yet).

Comment: The last LINQ query in my answer will give an IEnumerable of Row. When enumerating through them you have an IEnumerable called values containing the 3 values for that row. Because the value elements don't have attributes it is not possible to identify them as Term, Subject etc, they are all just value elements. If you have control over what the XML looks like then adding an attribute would give you a much nicer result when querying it